# Codeigniter attendance Module Looping result

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, loops

Hello I have been following a tutorial to help me with an attendance module I am making in Codeigniter.

I have events and in each event you can take attendance.

In my events View File, I am loading another View file called attendance.php.

The events view file shows all the event details with the attendance form embeded at the bottom.

The attendance form pulls in all the users who are registered and provides 2 radio buttons to mark whether the user has attended the event or not.

**This is the HTML I have got so far:**

```
<section class="content">
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>Event Attendance</h3>
      <?php echo form_open() ?>
        <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
                <thead>
                <tr class="">
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody_events">

                <?php 
                    $emp = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `aauth_users`");
                    $result = $emp->result();
                    settype($sl, "integer");

                    foreach($result as $row):
                        $sl++;

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $sl ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->id ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="emid[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->full_name ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="1" name="<?php echo $sl?>"> Present
                        <input type="radio" value="0" name="<?php echo $sl?>"> Absent
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Attendance" class="btn btn-success">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close() ?>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**The PHP Code I have**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $attid = $this->input->post('emid');
    $date = date("d-m-Y");
    $time = date("h:s:i A");
    $eventid = $events->id;
    $tm = count($attid);
    for($i=0;$i<$tm;$i++) {

        $at = $i+1;
        $attended = $_POST[$at];

        $attr = array(
            "user_id" => $attid[$i],
            "attended" => $attended,
            "attendance_date" => $date,
            "attendance_time" => $time,
            "event_id" => $eventid,
        );

    }

}

?>
```

**The Problem**
The problem I am having is everything is working great and I can take the attendance. I am seeing the results go into the database.

Every time I submit the attendance it is duplicating the attendance records. So currently I have 3 users registered. So on the events page down in the attendance table, it shows 3 users in each table row. Each have radio buttons to say 'present' or 'absent'. I submit the form and in the database I will have 6 entries. 2 from each user stating their attendance when I only need to show 1 entry for each user.
[image: my attendance form]

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out why I was adding duplicate results to the database.

I had an attendance View File, which I was calling from another View File. My submit function was in the attendance view, so because it was in the attendance view, which was also in the secondary view, it was running 2 times and therefore submitting a duplicate to the database.

Thank you to Francisco for kindly trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your database to see if you've utilised the enum data type. Now that I've removed the enum, everything is operating fine.

Answer (score -1):

You opened a form and closed it encapsulating all the inputs in your tables, except the submit button that is the same for each row. This is why this generates duplicates, because when you hit submit on one row it sends all the inputs inside the form (from all the other rows).

Isolate the form for each row:

```
<section class="content">
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <h3>Event Attendance</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
            <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Attendance</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody_events">

            <?php 
                $emp = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `aauth_users`");
                $result = $emp->result();
                settype($sl, "integer");

                foreach($result as $row):
                    $sl++;

                echo form_open(); // Form opens here for each row
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $sl ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->id ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="emid[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row->full_name ?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" name="<?php echo $sl?>"> Present
                    <input type="radio" value="0" name="<?php echo $sl?>"> Absent
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Attendance" class="btn btn-success">
                </td>
            </tr>
            echo form_close(); // Form closes here for each row
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current attendance form:
[image: my attendance form]

Comment: Hello Francisco, thank you for your kind suggestion, I made my code look like your suggestion but this just adds the Submit button to every row which I do not want to happen. I have a submit button in the table footer, so that when I check every radio button on each row I can then submit all results to the DB. -  I will add my attendance form layout as an image to the original question.